# MongoError: unknown top level operator: $expr

Tags: node.js, query, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando fazer isso no meu código e funciona perfeitamente no localhost porem no servidor da Umbler fica dando erro.

Segue o ERRO:

```
MongoError: unknown top level operator: $expr
```

Segue o codigo que estou tentando fazer no NodeJS com Mongosse:

```
await model('UsoApi').find({
    $and: [{
      $or: [
        { userIdDaChave: body.userIdDaChave },
        { chaveUsada: body.chaveUsada }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
          { "$eq": [{ "$year": "$createdAt" }, mesAno[1]] },
          { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$createdAt" }, mesAno[0]] }
        ]
      }
    }]
  }).sort({ createdAt: 'desc' });
```

Alguem consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

A coisa mais importante neste tipo de pergunta é especificar todas as diferenças entre os ambientes. Se funciona em um lugar e não funciona em outro, o mais provável sempre será que exista alguma diferença entre os ambientes.

Neste caso, como o operador `$expr` está disponível somente a partir da versão 3.6 do mongo, é importante verificar se a versão do Mongo DB no servidor é superior.

Em alternativa, para resolver a sua query, poderia experimentar usar o between entre 2 datas, especificando o ano e mês pretendidos com dia 1 como mínimo e (ano e mês) + 1 mês e dia 1 como máximo exclusivo.

```js
{
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        { userIdDaChave: body.userIdDaChave },
        { chaveUsada: body.chaveUsada }
      ]
    },
    {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: DATA_INICIAL,
        $lt: DATA_FINAL
    }
  ]
}
```